# JQuery Table with INPUT : Sum Columns and Rows

Tags: jquery, input, html-table, sum

I don't find anywhere a solution to calculate dynamically in a TABLE with INPUT the sum on each rows and each column and the sum of all inputs in the same time.
I've this HTML :

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th align=center>Ressource</th>
        <th align=center>Jan. (22j)<br></th>
        <th align=center>Fév. (20j)<br></th>
        <th align=center>Mars (22j)<br></th>
        <th align=center>Total:<br></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class='alt' onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='alt'">
    <td align=left>a</td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='1347_1'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='1347_2'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='1347_3'></td>
    <td align=right></td>
</tr>
<tr class='normal' onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='normal'">
    <td align=left>b</td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='4482_1'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='4482_2'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='4482_3'></td>
    <td align=right></td>
</tr>
<tr class='alt' onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='alt'">
    <td align=left>c</td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='7969_1'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='7969_2'></td>
    <td align=right><input class='saisie' type='text' size=4 name='7969_3'></td>
    <td align=right></td>
</tr>
<tr class="totalColumn">
    <td></td>
    <td class="totalCol" align=right>Total:</td>
    <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
    <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
    <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
    <td class="totalCol" align=right></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><span id=sum name sum></span>
```

and JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".saisie").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

for (i=0;i<$('#sum_table tr:eq(0) td').length;i++) {
   var total = 0;
    $('.saisie:eq(' + i + ')', 'tr').each(function(i) {
       total = total + parseFloat($(this).text());
    });            
    $('#sum_table tr:last td').eq(i).text(total);
}
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".saisie").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

So the global Sum works, but for the sum of all colums et all rows. I don't know.

Any ideas? Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code : add `calculateTotal` function with parameter `index`. Call this function by passing index of parent `td` of `input`. Now calculate sum for all `td` with same index and put it in total `td` of same index. call `calculateSum` from `calculateTotal` function.

**NOTE** - I have modified `calculateSum` function to avoid unecessary long for loop (counting `td` from `total` only)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".saisie").each(function() {
            $(this).keyup(function(){           
              calculateTotal($(this).parent().index());
            });
        });
    });
    function calculateTotal(index)
    {
       var total = 0;
        $('table tr td').filter(function(){
            if($(this).index()==index)
            {
            total += parseFloat($(this).find('.saisie').val())||0;
            }
        }
        );
        $('table tr td.totalCol:eq('+index+')').html(total);
       calculateSum();
       calculateRowSum(); 
    }

    function calculateSum() {
      var sum = 0;
      $("td.totalCol").each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).html())||0;
      });
      $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2)); 
   }

   function calculateRowSum()
   {
    $('table tr:has(td):not(:last)').each(function(){
      var sum = 0; 
      $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         sum += parseFloat($(this).find('.saisie').val()) || 0;
      });
       $(this).find('td:last').html(sum);
    });
  }
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/2789/)**

**NOTE** - I have removed first `td` from last row to make column alignment.

Comment: Works very well. THX.
But now did you know, how can I calculate the row sum ? With a sample ?